# Quiero redondear el numero e, pero el código no sale, me da error

Tags: java

```
public class Clasepower {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
      
      double Dato=2,718281828459045;
      double Resul=Math.round(Dato);
     
     System.out.println(Resul);
    }
}
```

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)! que error te da?

Comment: error: <identifier> expected

Comment: La traza de error, tan completa como sea posible, se pone EN la pregunta. El stacktrace da muchas pistas sobre lo que puede estar pasando

Comment: Estás poniendo el número con coma como separador de decimales. Si usas punto, de acuerdo a tu configuración regional, seguro funciona. Es pues, un error tipográfico

Comment: Gracias amigo, lo intentare

Answer (score 1):

Cambia

```
 double Dato=2,718281828459045;
```

por

```
 double Dato=2.718281828459045;
```

El detalle está en la coma, cámbialo por punto.